# Pasar un valor a un $_REQUEST

Tags: php, html, jquery

estoy integrandome al lenguaje php y no he podido obtener un valor al realizar $_REQUEST desde un archivo html y lo obtengo de manera vacia por lo cual no puedo agregar una nueva ruta de mis archivos a buscar, espero contar con ayuda para poder entender esta parte.

esta es la funcion:

´´´
function verdoc(branch,id,pag,texto){

```
         $('#prev').unbind();
         $('#sig').unbind();
         $( "#visor_body" ).html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Cargando...'>");
         $( "#visor" ).dialog({ title:texto, position: ['center','top'], modal : true,width:700, height:550,resizable:false });

          $.getJSON('visor.php?branch='+branch+'&id='+id+'&pag='+pag, function(data){ 
                   $('#prev').unbind().click(function (){verdoc(branch,id,data.prev,texto);return false;});
                   $('#sig').unbind().click(function (){verdoc(branch,id,data.next,texto);return false;});
                   if(parseInt(data.next)>=parseInt(data.total)){$('#sig').unbind();}
                   if(parseInt(data.prev)<0){$('#prev').unbind();}
                   $('#paginas').html(parseInt(parseInt(data.pag)+1)+" de "+data.total);
                   $('<img />')
                   .attr('src', 'pdoc.php?'+data.src+'&ids='+Math.random()).bind('contextmenu', function(e){
                        return false;
                    })
                    .load(function(){
                        $('#visor_body').html( $(this) );
                        // Your other custom code
                    });
                   //$( "#visor_body" ).html("<img src='pdoc.php?"+data.src+"'>");

                });
```

los parametros y el metodo post

```
<form method="post" action="{{url_post}}">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="descripcion" value="Número de parte : {{item.numero_parte}}, Juzgado:{{item.juzgado}}, Unidad Policial : {{item.unidad_policial}} "> 
                                        {%for itemdoc in item.lista_documentos%}
                                              <p><a id="link" href="#mid" onClick="verdoc('{{itemdoc.document_revision_id}}','0','<span style=\' font-size:14px;\'>Parte : {{item.numero_parte}}, {{itemdoc.fecha_entrega}}</span>');" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></a> Documento enviado: {{itemdoc.fecha_entrega}}&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="urls[]" value="{{itemdoc.document_revision_id}}"></p>       
                                        {%endfor%}
```

mi archivo para el request

```
<?php
require_once('seguridad.php');
require_once ('BptCdcClient.php');
$BptCliente=new BptCdcClient(WEB_SERVICE_URL);
$BptCliente->sessionId=$_SESSION['_ID_'];

if ($BptCliente->isAuth()){
$vertSize=(isset($_REQUEST["vertsize"]) && $_REQUEST["vertsize"]!="" ?                 $_REQUEST["vertsize"] : 600);
$textoMarcaAgua=MARCA_DE_AGUA;//VARIABLE DEFINIDA EN CONFIG.PHP
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFontSize( 100 );
/* Make the watermark semi-transparent */
$draw->setFillAlpha( 0.4 );

/* Set gravity to the center. More about gravity:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#gravity */
$draw->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );


$im = new imagick();
$im->setresolution(300, 300);
//Modifica Nicolás Villablanca 2020-02-10
//busqueda del documento en el treeFolder
$im->readimage('../dockeyst-cdc/upload/'.$_REQUEST["branch"].'        /'.$_REQUEST["id"].'['.$_REQUEST["pag"].']');
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->setcompressionquality(80);
$im->annotateImage( $draw, 0, 0, 45, $textoMarcaAgua );//Marca de agua
$im->resizeImage ( $vertSize, 0,  imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
ob_clean();
header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
echo $im;
}
?>
```

No logro anexar a mi archivo php el request por lo cual no logro encontrar la imagen necesaria para ser visualizada

Comment: Los parámetros enviados a PHP dependen del tipo de form que se envía, ya se `$_GET['var']` o `$_POST['var']`, en tu caso envias GET, intenta cambiarlo de esta forma.

Comment: En este caso logro obtener el request de id y pag pero no logro obtener en el archivo php que se solicita y me lo muestra en vacio ya los valores de mi nuevo request se muestran en otras vistas de php pero sin lograr en este archivo y no entiendo que podria sr

Comment: en el archivo visor.php logro capturar el valor de mi nuevo request pero en el archivo pdoc.php no logro capturarlo pero si a los demas

Comment: Debes ser más específico con lo que quieres obtener y lo que estás haciendo, por ejemplo, en visor.php si obtienes el valor, pero ¿cómo estás tratando de enviarlo a pdoc.php? ¿Usas include, otro formulario o qué? Por favor edita tu pregunta y especifica a qué archivo corresponde cada código que pusiste.